# Rails constant lookup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a question about setting up constants in Rails project.

From Dan Chak's Enterprise Rails book, he explains that constant lookup code like below gets executed only once when the app starts. However, looking at the log, I think it gets run every time I use the constant.

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  USER = Role.find_by_key('user')
  ADMIN = Role.find_by_key('admin')
end
```

This definitely allows cleaner code as I can do something like:

```
current_user.role = Role::ADMIN
```

As an alternative, I read about `ActiveSupport::Memoizable`, but I want to confirm this setup results in multiple db lookup before changing my code around.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code will only get executed once each time your environment is loaded. This will happen often in development and test environments, but only once each time an app server is spawned in production.

Comment: Thanks @tilleryj, could you elaborate little more? Does the rails env get loaded several times in development? I see those constants lookup every time I refresh a page that references one of the constants. Just trying to understand why it happens in development.

Comment: All your application code is reloaded on every request in development mode, so that changes you make can be instantly tested. If you want, you can change `cache_classes` to true in your `development.rb` to see how things will load in production.

Answer (score 2):

How about putting it in your config/initializers/constants.rb?

That ensure that it will only be called once on app start

just put

```
USER = Role.find_by_key('user')
ADMIN = Role.find_by_key('admin')
```

and you can use the USER/ADMIN constant in your app

Comment: Thanks @corroded. Actually I have a set of domain data in other models as well, and I'd like to keep them in their model definition, not in an initializer.

Comment: not sure but I think you can still set the initializer to have a domain like you would like. Just use Role::USER = Role.find_by_key('user')